# where should click event add after inherit window?

Tags: inheritance, f#

The following test code, when open window, it will pop up hello messagebox too. It sounds that it run the code after `fun _ ->` when open window.
When i debug to see without test001, it seems not run one by one, like not run the code after `fun _ ->`:

```
let test001 = MessageBox.Show("hello")
type Server() as this =
    inherit windows
       do connectionButton.Click.Add (fun _ -> test001
                                            tc.Connect("localhost", 2626) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `test001` is a value, it is only evaluated once. What you need is a function which will popup a MessageBox each time it is called:

```
let test001() = MessageBox.Show("hello") // test001 is now a function
type Server() as this =
    inherit windows
       do connectionButton.Click.Add (fun _ -> test001() |> ignore
                                               tc.Connect("localhost", 2626))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `Server` like this

Assuming `Server` inherits from `System.Windows.Form`

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Server())
```